# Error message in `autolayer()`: No autolayer method avialable for <gg> objects

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

There are multiple posts with errors using `autolayer()` after `autoplot()`. Some answers suggest specifying the package, or calling different packages. However, none works in this case, and the message is different from others in other posts.

Here is the code from [this online book](https://otexts.com/fpp3/) (I'm including all the libraries called, and exactly the tweak in calling for the function that I attempted):

```
# From https://otexts.com/fpp3/
library(quantmod)
library(forecast)
library(ggplot2)
library(fpp3)
library(ggfortify)
library(feasts)

us_retail_employment <- us_employment |>
  filter(year(Month) >= 1990, Title == "Retail Trade")

dcmp <- us_retail_employment |> 
  model(stl = STL(Employed))
components(dcmp) |> 
  autoplot()

us_retail_employment |> 
  autoplot(Employed, color = 'gray') |> 
  forecast::autolayer(ts(components(dcmp)$trend), color = 'blue') +
  labs(y = 'Persons (thousands)', title='Total employment in US Retail')
```

Comment: The packages you call are certainly not recommended in my book. You only need the fpp3 package. In particular, don't use the ggfortify package. It doesn't play nicely with other packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `ggplot`, we add layers with `+`, not with `|>`. This feels a bit unexpected with the function producing the layer doesn't start with `geom_` or `stat_`

```r
us_retail_employment |> 
  autoplot(Employed, color = 'gray') +
  forecast::autolayer(ts(components(dcmp)$trend), color = 'blue') +
  labs(y = 'Persons (thousands)', title='Total employment in US Retail')
```

[image]

Comment: Yes! Here is the code as it should be (incorporating your answer): `us_retail_employment |> 
  autoplot(Employed, color = 'gray') +
  forecast::autolayer(components(dcmp), trend, color = 'blue') +
  labs(y = 'Persons (thousands)', title='Total employment in US Retail')`

Answer (score 0):

This is quite an interesting case that arose in my learning process too.

The following code has been taken from the boor "Forecasting: Principles and Practice" and yielded an error that I haven't been able to correct so far:

```
autoplot(HS030191_CH_PrVal_ts_train) +
  forecast::autolayer (meanf(HS030191_CH_PrVal_ts_train,h=12),
            series = "Mean",
            PI = FALSE) + # Logical flag indicating whether to plot prediction intervals.
  autolayer(naive(HS030191_CH_PrVal_ts_train, h = 12),
            series = "Naive",
            PI = FALSE) +
  autolayer(snaive(HS030191_CH_PrVal_ts_train, h = 12),
            series = "Seasonal naive",
            PI = FALSE)
```

`HS030191_CH_PrVal_ts_train` is a simple ts() object that is supposed to be supplied to the `autolayer()` function, but the outcome I got looks the following:

```
Error in `transformation$transform()`:
! `transform_date()` works with objects of class <Date> only
```

Please, let me know what I did wrong.

Thanks a lot!